# Has setDisabled been deprecated? I'm getting this error - formContext.ui.tabs.get(...).setDisabled is not a function

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, powerapps-modeldriven

I've been receiving the following error in my code once I've injected it onto my form - formContext.ui.tabs.get(...).setDisabled is not a function

```
function HideAndDisableTabsBasedOnBPFStage(executionContext) {
    var formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();
    
    // Hide and disable tabs based on the current BPF stage
    var bpfStageId = formContext.data.process.getActiveStage().getId();
    switch (bpfStageId) {
        case "abbda151-be8f-462a-99b9-b32231baadaf":
            // Hide and disable tabs for Request stage
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Requestor").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CourtApprover").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_JBSIS").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTS").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Finance").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTSEntry").setVisible(false);
            break;
        case "ea3aa60c-f952-4edb-b955-c78c2cebc3a6":
            // Hide and disable tabs for Court Approver stage
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Requestor").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CourtApprover").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_JBSIS").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTS").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Finance").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTSEntry").setVisible(false);
            break;
        case "0d92ffa6-786d-4e4b-b790-695f4495c7a7":
            // Hide and disable tabs for Court Approver (non-charging) stage
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Requestor").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CourtApprover").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_JBSIS").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTS").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Finance").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTSEntry").setVisible(false);
            break;
        case "bdcfd44f-6b69-47ef-9785-a7a3c029169c":
            // Hide and disable tabs for JBSIS stage
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Requestor").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Requestor").setDisabled(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CourtApprover").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CourtApprover").setDisabled(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_JBSIS").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTS").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Finance").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTSEntry").setVisible(false);
            break;
        case "bccdfa2d-831a-4f4e-a370-c0d3b130914b":
            // Hide and disable tabs for Finance stage
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Requestor").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Requestor").setDisabled(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CourtApprover").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CourtApprover").setDisabled(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_JBSIS").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTS").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Finance").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTSEntry").setVisible(false);
            break;
        case "fcfaceed-fc37-4dde-9351-f8942fe2b73f":
            // Hide and disable tabs for CTS Review stage
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Requestor").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Requestor").setDisabled(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CourtApprover").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CourtApprover").setDisabled(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_JBSIS").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTS").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Finance").setVisible(false);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTSEntry").setVisible(false);
            break;
        case "f712096e-f750-4b6e-a10e-0e8d3184387e":
            // Hide and disable tabs for CTS Entry stage
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Requestor").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Requestor").setDisabled(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CourtApprover").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CourtApprover").setDisabled(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_JBSIS").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_JBSIS").setDisabled(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTS").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTS").setDisabled(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Finance").setVisible(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_Finance").setDisabled(true);
            formContext.ui.tabs.get("tab_CTSEntry").setVisible(true);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

// Add event handlers for OnLoad and OnStageChange events
Xrm.Page.data.process.addOnLoad(HideAndDisableTabsBasedOnBPFStage);
Xrm.Page.data.process.addOnStageChange(HideAndDisableTabsBasedOnBPFStage);
```

Thanks in advance!

I'd also like to note that if I delete all the setDisabled code and leave the setVisible code, the script executes perfectly. Not sure why it is not working for setDisabled even though I see a lot of documentation online where the code is the same in my script above.

Comment: `setDisabled` is a member of `control` and `quickViewControl`, I can't see it as a member of `tab` at any point in the documentation's history. Where is the "lot of documentation online" where it's the same as your script?

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine 
Apologies, I misspoke. The code I was working with in ChatGPT gave me those lines. I can't find the setDisable function in the documentation.  I was wondering if there is a way to have certain tabs as 'read-only' when the business process flow reaches a certain stage?

Comment: ChatGPT gave you those lines because it doesn't actually _know_ things, it just regurgitates things that it think sound plausible. In this case, sounded plausible, but incorrect. I'd use this as a learning exercise, ChatGPT has its uses, but for a lot of code tasks, it's not at all capable. I _imagine_ the best option is to instead disable all controls within the tab, rather than the tab itself, but am uncertain.

Comment: @NickstandswithUkraine I posted some links but they were about setVisible and not setDisabled, apologies for the mistake

Answer (score 1):

You can have a reusable function and use it like this.

```
EnableDisableTabControls(formContext, “tab_CourtApprover”, true);
```

**Reusable function**:

```
function EnableDisableTabControls(formContext, tabName, disableStatus) {  
         var sectionName = formContext.ui.tabs.get(tabName).sections.get();
         for (var i in sectionName) {
         var controls = sectionName[i].controls.get();
         var controlsLength = controls.length;
         for (var i = 0; i < controlsLength; i++) {
             controls[i].setDisabled(disableStatus);
          }
        }
    }
```